# How to delete Ghost Menu Link in Main Menu?

Tags: routes

I added a menu link in main menu: `user/%/notifications/subscription`. The menu is never visible except that when a user goes to his subscription page via 'My Account'. The menu link is not available when I try to edit the main menu links. It is not there. This problem surfaced up after I installed [Menu Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) module. However, I committed the sin before installing the Menu Token] module. I have uninstalled this module.

Additionally, user gets the following error when visiting `user/%/notifications/subscription`.

> "Notice: Undefined index: localized_options in menu_navigation_links() (line 1858 of /home/carrotjo/public_html/includes/menu.inc)."

After some search on the Internet, I commented out `$l = $item['link']['localized_options'];` (line 1857 in menu.inc). The error is gone. But the ghost appears in the main menu link.

Comment: Try clearing your Drupal cache.  Before you do though, I would recommend removing any modifications to Drupal core that may have been made.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to manually delete this item from the table `menu_links` search for value `user/%/notifications/subscription` in `link_path` column. Delete that row and clear your cache.